# Mock in .Net MS Test

Tags: c#, .net, mocking

I am trying to test by Moq one of the controller method in WEB API.

`

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<Task> GetTaskById([FromRoute] int id)

{
      var task = _task.GetTaskById(id);
```

```
      var taskResponse = new TaskResponse
        {
            Id = task.Id,
            Name = task.Name,
        };

        return Ok(taskResponse);
}
```

Also have ServiceClass that have interface for each method:

```
public interface ITask
{
    Task GetTaskById(int id);
    IEnumerable<Task > GetAllTasks();
}
```

```
public class TaskService: ITask
{
    private readonly TaskPlannerDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly ILogger<TaskService> _logger;
```

```
public TaskService(TaskPlannerDbContext dbContext, ILogger<TaskService> logger)
{
    _dbContext = dbContext;
    _logger = logger;
}


public IEnumerable<Task> GetAllTasks()
{
        var tasks = _dbContext.Tasks.AsEnumerable();

        return tasks;
}
```

```
}
```

My already test:

```
        var mockExpanse = new Task();

        var data = new List<Task>
        {
            new Expense { Id = 1, Name = "BBB"},
            new Expense { Id = 2, Name = "ZZZ"},
            new Expense { Id = 3, Name = "AAA"},
        }.AsQueryable();

        var tasksDbSetMock= new Mock<DbSet<Task>>();
        tasksDbSetMock.As<IQueryable<Task>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        tasksDbSetMock.As<IQueryable<Task>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        tasksDbSetMock.As<IQueryable<Task>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        tasksDbSetMock.As<IQueryable<Task>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => data.GetEnumerator());

        var dbContextMock = new Mock<TaskPlannerDbContext >();
        dbContextMock.Setup(c => c.tasks).Returns(tasksDbSetMock.Object);

        var service = new TaskService(dbContextMock.Object, loggerMock.Object);
        var tasks2 = service.GetAllTasks();

        Assert.AreEqual(3, tasks2.Count());`
```

But I get exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Unsupported expression: c => c.Tasks
> Non-overridable members (here: TaskPlannerDbContext.get_Tasks) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.'

`dbContextMock.Setup(c => c.tasks).Returns(tasksDbSetMock.Object);`

What can I fix in my test ?
Maybe I should change approach to test by Mocking  ?

Comment: Don't try to mock an EF DbContext unless you really know what you are doing (and really need to).  Use the Inmemory provider instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/

Comment: "But I get exception" - what is the exception message (quite surprising that you get that far so - I'd expect compile error)... Please [edit] the post with the exact error message as text and missing pieces of an [mre] - in particular `TaskPlannerDbContext` type the code is mocking missing from the sample. Also none of the test's code test any controller methods - mayby look into that too while editing the post.

Comment: I fix my code in post.

_task is inject by Dependecy Injection and type is ITask